# How to ping a computer inside a subnet setup using vmware's virtual network editor connected via NAT?

Tags: networking, ping, subnet, vmware-workstation

My Computer runs 3 VMs: **vmInfra**(10.0.99.99), **vmPrime**(10.0.99.11) and **vmDeux**(10.0.99.12). The setup looks like this:

[image: Network Structure]

When I ping my physical host (10.0.99.1) from any of the VMs, it can find it, but when I ping any of the VMs from the host, the host tries to ping some computer on the internet (probably) since the VMs share a private IP range. How do I fix this?

My Host has the following IP setup:

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto static metric 600 
10.0.99.0/24 dev vmnet99 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.99.1 
172.16.8.0/24 dev vmnet1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.8.1 
172.16.33.0/24 dev vmnet8 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.33.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.73 metric 600 

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:52:82:b9:05:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:95:09:de:4e:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.73/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlo1
       valid_lft 82559sec preferred_lft 82559sec
    inet6 fe80::6528:e383:1754:9aef/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: vmnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.8.1/24 brd 172.16.8.255 scope global vmnet1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: vmnet8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.33.1/24 brd 172.16.33.255 scope global vmnet8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vmnet99: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.99.1/24 brd 10.0.99.255 scope global vmnet99
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:63/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The VMware virtual Network Manager generated a `/etc/vmware/vmnet99/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf` file that has the following contents:

```
 allow unknown-clients;
 default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes
 max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours

 subnet 10.0.99.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
     range 10.0.99.128 10.0.99.254;
     option broadcast-address 10.0.99.255;
     option domain-name-servers 10.0.99.2;
     option domain-name localdomain;
     default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes
     max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours
     option netbios-name-servers 10.0.99.2;
     option routers 10.0.99.2;
 }
 host vmnet99 {
     hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:63;
     fixed-address 10.0.99.1;
     option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
     option domain-name "";
     option routers 0.0.0.0;
 }
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question to: https://superuser.com/questions/1295297/how-to-ping-a-computer-inside-a-subnet-setup-using-vmwares-virtual-network-edit

Comment: @essjae as u can see, that question was migrated to this site, over which i had zero control.